# javascript split string selected text replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Hello javascript split selected text replace?

```
var words = "Red,Blue,Yellow";
words.replace('Blue','White') == "White";
console.log(words);
```

not working

result: Red,White,Yellow

Comment: Why do you compare the replaced string with "White"?

Comment: `words.replace('Blue','White') == "White";` makes no sense

Comment: Have you even tried the code?? `words.replace('Blue', 'White') doesn't even give you 'White' - it gives your 'Red,White,Yellow'...

Comment: I want to change the location of a selected word

Comment: What do you mean by "change the location"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to replace `Blue` with `White` in the `words` string, you need to re-assign the returned string to the `words` variable. The `replace` method does not edit the string in-place.

```
var words = "Red,Blue,Yellow";
words = words.replace('Blue','White');
console.log(words);
```

There is no reason to compare the return value of `words` with what you are trying to replace.